# Any way or app to enable vibrate only mode in Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, vibration, silent-mode

I have a Moto G and earlier the Moto Assist used to have a setting to put phone in Vibrate only mode while in meetings. On updating to Lollipop, I don't have this option.

I know that it's possible to manually set phone in vibrate mode. But I have to this each time, instead of Phone automatically going to Vibrate mode checking my calender meetings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like IFTTT (If this then that) app + the online service to connect to your calendar.
Here is a sample recipe.
https://ifttt.com/recipes/165618-mute-phone-when-calendar-event-starts

Comment: Motorola assist already checks my calendar puts it in mute. I need it to be in vibrate only

Comment: I just showed you the example, you can create a new recipe and use vibrate mode only. You can also use an app like Trigger for the same thing.

Comment: Looks like the linked IFTTT recipe has gone...